# Android Datagram Socket Throws "NetworkOnMainThreadException" instead of "SocketException"

Tags: java, android, sockets

In DatagramSocket reference ([link to reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html)), it is shown that

`public void connect (SocketAddress peer)`

function throws `SocketException` if an error occurs but in fact it may throw `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when the function runs on UI thread in Honeycomb or higher.

So my question is why `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is not written under **Throws** title and only `SocketException` is written?

Answer (score 3):

Because `SocketException` is a [checked exception](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions), and `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is an [unchecked exception](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Unchecked_Exceptions).